# Autorange BarChart with ReferenceLine using Material-UI x-chart

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, charts, material-ui

Using React, [Material-UI](https://mui.com/), and the [`BarChart`](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/bars/#basics) component - is there a standard way to autorange the Y-Axis of a stacked bar-chart so that the plot will be sure to include any [`ChartsReferenceLine`](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/axis/#reference-line) elements, as well as the plotted data?

I have a simple `BarChart` with a single `ChartsReferenceLine`:

```html
<BarChart
    xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'band', data: ['group A'] }]}
    series={[{ data: [4] }, { data: [1] }, { data: [2] }]}
    width={500}
    height={300}
  >
  <ChartsReferenceLine
    y={10}
    lineStyle={{ strokeDasharray: "10 5", strokeWidth: "2" }}
   />
</BarChart>
```

but the `ChartsReferenceLine` ends up off the chart since its value is so much higher than the plotted elements. I know that I can compute the max ahead of time and use the axis [`max`](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/axis/#axis-sub-domain) to set it myself, but is there an automatic method to do this?